# How to iterate over arrays of arrays n level deep without recursion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have something like:

```
[ {}, {children:[{}, {}]} , {} ]  #each element cane be any level deep
```

and want to iterate over it without recursion. Just to test performance benefits. Any help?

Comment: Well, no, I don't think it's possible without recursion. But the true question is: why should you do this without recursion?

Comment: I implemented with recursion and it works well, but manager suggested to implement via iteration as it might be faster. So trying to profile the two and see. This could be for large data set so there might be a significant difference

Comment: I am not totally sure about it, but I don't think you can do that with iteration, because if you write **n** deep iterations and you get an object which is **n+1** deep your function wouldn't work well(it would leave the last level unparsed). Say that to your manager :P

Comment: This is one of those instances where recursion is faster.

Comment: also it sounds like your manager is trying to prematurely optimize

Comment: @JustenMartin you may be right about recursion being faster, but don't really know until I test it out. Anyways, I think I can use the pre-order tree traversal algorithm via stack based for this.

Comment: @user814628 Your manager doesn't seem to understand that.

Comment: @LightStyle No I think there is a iterative solution. Each object in the array is a graph(sort of), so I guess its more like a list of tree tranversal instead of just one tree transversal.

Comment: Actually, @LightStyle you might be correct

Answer (score 1):

Every resursive function can be shortcutted into a function, that keeps its own stack - the question is: Is it faster? I guess not.

What I mean here is something like (in pseudo-code)

```
function flatten(something) {
  var ping=[];
  var pong=[];
  repeat {
    if (ping is empty) {
      if (something is empty) break;
      else ping.prepend(something.shift());
    }

    var element=ping.shift();
    if (element has children)
      foreach (child of element in reverse order) ping.prepend(child);
    else
      pong.append(element);
  }

  return pong;
}
```

calling `flatten(your_input_object)` will result in a "naive humanlike enumeration" list of its entries

Comment: cool cool, yea in this case we flatten then iterate whereas in recursive we iterative as we go. So recursion might be faster, I would assume

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but if you're able to check if there is a following element in the array, can you write a nested while loop?